# timer in console application

Tags: c#, timer, compact-framework

I am creating a device application using .NET compact framework 2.0. There is a `system.threading.timer` in my application which executes some code. It works fine. My problem is when I am running the app by double clicking on the exe in the bin folder, the timer starts and execute all it works but it never stops. It runs in the background even after closing the app by clicking the X-button or from the file menu close button. I don't understand how and where I stop or dispose of the timer so that it doesn't run after closing the app. May be something like a form_closing event in window form application. I had searched a lot in Google but did't find any proper answer.

The application is use to generate digital output for a device
here is some code of timer event:

```
public static void Main()
{
   // Some code related to the device like open device etc
   // Then the timer
   System.Threading.Timer stt =
       new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(TimerProc), null, 1, 5000);
        Thread.CurrentThread.Join();
}

static void TimerProc(Object stateInfo)
{
    // It is my local method which will execute in time interval,
    // uses to write value to the device
    writeDigital(1, 0);

    GC.Collect();
}
```

It is working fine when I run the code in debug mode, timer stops when I stop the program. But not working when I run the exe.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: "Note that callbacks can occur after the Dispose() method overload has been called, because the timer queues callbacks for execution by thread pool threads"

Comment: @Ewan what do i do? can you please explain?

Comment: post more code, specificaly your app start and end or main functions and explain what you are using the timer for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create and dispose it in `Main()` and pass it to any methods that require it?

```
private static void Main()
{
    using (var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerProc))
    {
        // Rest of code here...
    }
}
```

More importantly, this line of code:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.Join();
```

will never return, because you are asking the current thread to wait for the current thread to terminate. Think about that for a moment... ;)

So your solution is probably to just remove that line of code.

Comment: its working after a little change, i have put a console.readline() there, and its done.. thank u sir

Answer (score 0):

All about GC.Collect();

Your stt object is used once and after that is pointed out to being removed and its memory reclaimed.

If you don't belive call stt.ToString(); at the end of main function, it will extend the stt live till the end of main function.

Solution(s)?

- You can define the stt object as a static - it guarantees that it will be alive till the end of live of you program
- recommended solution is to use GC.KeepAlive(stt); which you can call at the end of main function which will keep the stt away from destroying process.